# How to use Maximum in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

i want to filter my rows and only select/ display my rows when the field AMSD135.AB is the latest date date in that group.

So i got a report with some groups where the last group is grouped on AMSD135.AB. Now i created a formula to hide the section.

```
AMSD135.AB <> Maximum({AMSD135.AB}, {AMSD135.AB})
```

but i always get the following error message:

```
There must be a group that matches this field.
```

if i use

```
AMSD135.AB <> Maximum({AMSD135.AB})
```

it searches for the max in all rows.

Comment: What field is being used to create the group?

Comment: Groupfield is AMSD135.AB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when i use the following formula:

```
{AMSD135.AB} <> Maximum({AMSD135.AB},{Arbeitsgang.AGNR})
```

with `{Arbeitsgang.AGN}` being the group above. Which makes more sense, since when i group by AB, `Max(AB)` is always AB. But shouldnt it still work.